# jarsigner error: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0

Tags: java, android, linux, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I get this error when signing an Ionic android apk, I'm on Kubuntu 17.04, using Ionic 3, java 8 installed

The error I get:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore: 
updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
adding: META-INF/TEST2.SF
adding: META-INF/TEST2.RSA
signing: AndroidManifest.xml
jarsigner error: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
```

java version

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

javac

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

I have Android Studio installed and it's working fine, I tested the app source code and it ran on the emulator no problems.

Comment: were you able to get this fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue could be solved on **Debian 9** by setting the correct update-alternative for jarsigner that matches the version of java and javac.

Version of java

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-1~deb9u1-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

Version of javac

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_141
```

Version of jarsigner

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep jarsigner
jarsigner   manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner
```

To set the version of jarsigner

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config jarsigner
There are 4 choices for the alternative jarsigner (providing /usr/bin/jarsigner).

  Selection    Path                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner   1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gjarsigner-4.9                           1049      manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gjarsigner-6                             1060      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner   1081      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner   1091      manual mode
```

Comment: I had the same issue with version 9, after updating to 10, the problem is gone. Here you can find how to install/update version 10 or later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507161/6053654

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. But my java version is 9.0.1,after switched my jdk version to 1.8.xx, the error was gone.
So, change the jdk version may solve the problem.