# Jarsigner error: Invalid value for MonthOfYear

Tags: android, jarsigner

When trying to sign an unsigned release apk, I'm using the following command in terminal:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore My_Key_Sign.keystore app-myapp-release-unsigned.apk 'my app name'
```

We've done this with every release and it has always worked.  Starting yesterday, we started seeing terminal return this error:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore: 
 updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/MY_APP.SF
   adding: META-INF/MY_APP.RSA
  signing: META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader
jarsigner error: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
```

Any idea as to why this would start happening?

EDIT: this **might be** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46508081/1409132) but it didn't have any answers