# E: Unable to locate package openjdk-11-jdk

Tags: maven, docker, debian, java-11

I try to create docker image:

It is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11

# Common files and utils for build
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make fakeroot rpm dpkg-dev apt-utils wget unzip
RUN apt-get install -y -q software-properties-common desktop-file-utils

# Then Wine with all deps
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --install-recommends wine
RUN apt-cache search openjdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
RUN apt install -y openjfx11 libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni
RUN apt-get install -y --install-recommends wine32

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV JAVAFX_HOME /usr/share/java/openjfx11

# And we ready to play with our code
ARG SRCDIR=.
ARG DSTDIR=/usr/src/CryptoStock
ARG CACHEDIR=./cache

# Subject to be used here but should be command line, sic!
# ADD ${CACHEDIR} /root/.m2
# ADD ${SRCDIR} /mnt/src

RUN mkdir -p /root/.m2/repository
COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
COPY settings-security.xml /root/.m2/settings-security.xml
COPY jdk11-build-in-docker.sh ${DSTDIR}/jdk11-build-in-docker.sh

COPY ./static/. ${DSTDIR}/static
COPY ./3rdparty/. ${DSTDIR}/3rdparty
COPY ./winjdk11/. ${DSTDIR}/winjdk

ENV SOURCES /usr/src/CryptoStock
ENV OUTSIDE /mnt/src

RUN dpkg -l '*openjfx*'
RUN dpkg -l '*jdk*'

WORKDIR ${DSTDIR}

CMD [ "sh", "/usr/src/CryptoStock/jdk11-build-in-docker.sh" ]
```

When I try to build I don't to watch java 11:

```
Step 6/27 : RUN apt-cache search openjdk
 ---> Running in e03b4c69fa69
jtreg - Regression Test Harness for the OpenJDK platform
openjdk-8-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-8-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-8-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-8-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-8-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-8-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-8-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-8-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-8-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
openjdk-8-jre-dcevm - Alternative VM for OpenJDK 8 with enhanced class redefinition
uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-8 - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 8)
uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-8 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 8)
uwsgi-plugin-ring-openjdk-8 - Closure/Ring plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 8)
uwsgi-plugin-servlet-openjdk-8 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 8)
Removing intermediate container e03b4c69fa69
 ---> 1fae3b35c58b
Step 7/27 : RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
 ---> Running in 288fb5247ce6
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-11-jdk
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

There is only java 8, there is no java 11.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504825/how-to-install-jdk-11-under-ubuntu

Comment: Why do you want to try to install jdk11 in a docker image that comes with it already?

Comment: Thanks to Matt Schuchard for komment. I added java -version in Dockerfile and there realy was set open jdk 11.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK 11 is installed by default in the maven:3-jdk-11 image:

```
$ docker run maven:3-jdk-11 java --version

openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.16+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.16+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It is also available via the Debian package system:

```
$ docker run maven:3-jdk-11 sh -c 'apt update && apt-cache search openjdk-11'

[...]
openjdk-11-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-11-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-11-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-11-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-11-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-11-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-11-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-11-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
openjdk-11-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
[...]
```

Today the maven:3-jdk-11 image is using Debian 11 (Bullseye), but when you wrote your question the maven:3-jdk-11 image was probably using a Debian 9 (Stretch) image with OpenJDK 11 installed but not available through the Debian package system. This explains your error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below two lines before **RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk** in your Dockerfile

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update