# Java 11 installation problem for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, java-11

I've tried all the ways but somehow I can't install java 11.
Showing my previous version of java

I did following steps:

**STEP 1:** I Installed : `jdk-11.0.8_linux-x64_bin.deb` file from Oracle website.

**STEP 2:** Run this command :  `sudo dpkg -i jdk-11.0.8_linux-x64_bin.deb`

**STEP 3:** `sudo get update`

**STEP 4:** run this command  `sudo vim /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`

**STEP 5:** Add this line in empty folder:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And save this file. Than I checked in `usr/lib/jvm` path with `ls`
I get:

```
default-java@  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64@  java-8-openjdk-amd64/  jdk-11.0.8/
```

Than I enter this command:

```
source /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

I get these output:

```
    set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/home/duygu/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/duygu/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/home/duygu/.local/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/duygu/.local/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/local/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/sbin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/local/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/sbin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /sbin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/games may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/games'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/local/games may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/games'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/snap/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /snap/bin'?
set: Warning: path component /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin:/usr/local/jdk-11.0.2/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/jdk-11.0.2/bin'?
```

When I check the java -version I get: `openjdk version "1.8.0_265"`

And enter this command : `update-java-alternatives --list` I get:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I tried sudo reboot and tried again and I didnt install java 11 . How can I install ? Where is my fault ?

**EDITED:**

I've already tried this lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

I get error like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-11-jdk is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java15-installer 15-1~linuxuprising3
  oracle-java14-installer 14.0.2-1~linuxuprising1
  oracle-java11-installer-local 11.0.8-1~linuxuprising0
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'openjdk-11-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Why the complicated installation using downloads and not use `apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk`, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504825/how-to-install-jdk-11-under-ubuntu. Also this should be on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Ive already tried but I get error I mentioned about it new edited

Comment: @matt how can I solve this?

Comment: I found this installation method in https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-11-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/ So I am using this steps

Comment: @matt I have already tried installing them I get a has no installation candidate error in all of the recommended installations

Comment: But also I've tried like export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH and it does not work

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more of a question for askubuntu.com It also needs more focus. It's just chaos at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this after installing,

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8"
```

Note that, `/bin` is not to be included. Save and exit. Then,

```
source /etc/environment
```

Btw, why complicate a normal installation?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added this lines and run source /etc/enviroment I get this error: Unsupported use of '='. In fish, please use 'set JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8'.
/etc/environment (line 2): JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8"

Comment: @hobik I thought you were using bash shell. In fish shell, setting a variable is different. Try 

In set command, I don't know if  `quotes` can be used or not. Try `set JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8` or `set JAVA_HOME '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8'`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably install java 11 by the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504825/how-to-install-jdk-11-under-ubuntu) to see how to install openjdk 11 on ubuntu.

Then you can run the

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

to update the java version. You can refer this [link](https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zuludocs/ZuluUserGuide/SwitchingBetweenJavaAlternatives/SwitchBetweenYourLinuxZuluInstallations.htm) to see how to update java alternatives.

Comment: When I did all those things, I tried your suggestion but I get error I will add in my topic please look again.

Comment: Try adding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa` instead of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java` then run the installation commands