# Omnet++ 5.4.1 running error on Ubuntu 18.10 after succesfull installation

Tags: java, ubuntu, omnet++

There is an error like java runtime environment version 11 is not capable of running eclipse.

But I do not understand required jre version is 8 or upper.

Should I have to downgrade JRE version?

Here is error details when I run `da@n53sm:~$ tail -f omnetpp-5.4.1/samples/.metadata/.log` command.

```
2019-01-09 log tracing

!SESSION 2019-01-09 17:09:25.101 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=5.4.1.180629-5e28390
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-09 17:09:27.757
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-01-09 17:09:27.769
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 21 more
```

My java version is:

```
da@n53sm:~$ java --version 
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I've looked some pages. The solution is downgrading the JRE to version 8.x.

Comment: Would you like to share the exact error message?

Comment: @thardes2 Does this help? I've added error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer from OMNET++ mailing list.

Adding configuration to your `config.ini` solves the problem asked.

Here is the link for the topic of mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/omnetpp/t13qEhyyuqI/discussion

> I know it's super ugly, but OMNeT++ 5.4.1 is based on Eclipse 4.7.3
>   and The java 11 broke the compatibility with Eclipse 4.7 which in turn
>   causes the issue with OMNeT++ 5.4.1.
>
> A very quick workaround would be to downgrade your java package to
>   1.8, though I'm not sure that is definitely possible.
>
> An other workaround is to paste the following in the
>   ide/configuration/config.ini (obviously we may need to release omnet
>   5.4.2 to fix this with an updated eclipse) Hope it helps

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages = \
 javax.accessibility,\
 javax.activation,\
 javax.activity,\
 javax.crypto,\
 javax.crypto.interfaces,\
 javax.crypto.spec,\
 javax.imageio,\
 javax.imageio.event,\
 javax.imageio.metadata,\
 javax.imageio.plugins.bmp,\
 javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,\
 javax.imageio.spi,\
 javax.imageio.stream,\
 javax.jws,\
 javax.jws.soap,\
 javax.lang.model,\
 javax.lang.model.element,\
 javax.lang.model.type,\
 javax.lang.model.util,\
 javax.management,\
 javax.management.loading,\
 javax.management.modelmbean,\
 javax.management.monitor,\
 javax.management.openmbean,\
 javax.management.relation,\
 javax.management.remote,\
 javax.management.remote.rmi,\
 javax.management.timer,\
 javax.naming,\
 javax.naming.directory,\
 javax.naming.event,\
 javax.naming.ldap,\
 javax.naming.spi,\
 javax.net,\
 javax.net.ssl,\
 javax.print,\
 javax.print.attribute,\
 javax.print.attribute.standard,\
 javax.print.event,\
 javax.rmi,\
 javax.rmi.CORBA,\
 javax.rmi.ssl,\
 javax.script,\
 javax.security.auth,\
 javax.security.auth.callback,\
 javax.security.auth.kerberos,\
 javax.security.auth.login,\
 javax.security.auth.spi,\
 javax.security.auth.x500,\
 javax.security.cert,\
 javax.security.sasl,\
 javax.sound.midi,\
 javax.sound.midi.spi,\
 javax.sound.sampled,\
 javax.sound.sampled.spi,\
 javax.sql,\
 javax.sql.rowset,\
 javax.sql.rowset.serial,\
 javax.sql.rowset.spi,\
 javax.swing,\
 javax.swing.border,\
 javax.swing.colorchooser,\
 javax.swing.event,\
 javax.swing.filechooser,\
 javax.swing.plaf,\
 javax.swing.plaf.basic,\
 javax.swing.plaf.metal,\
 javax.swing.plaf.multi,\
 javax.swing.plaf.nimbus,\
 javax.swing.plaf.synth,\
 javax.swing.table,\
 javax.swing.text,\
 javax.swing.text.html,\
 javax.swing.text.html.parser,\
 javax.swing.text.rtf,\
 javax.swing.tree,\
 javax.swing.undo,\
 javax.tools,\
 javax.xml,\
 javax.xml.bind,\
 javax.xml.bind.annotation,\
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,\
 javax.xml.bind.attachment,\
 javax.xml.bind.helpers,\
 javax.xml.bind.util,\
 javax.xml.crypto,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dom,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,\
 javax.xml.datatype,\
 javax.xml.namespace,\
 javax.xml.parsers,\
 javax.xml.soap,\
 javax.xml.stream,\
 javax.xml.stream.events,\
 javax.xml.stream.util,\
 javax.xml.transform,\
 javax.xml.transform.dom,\
 javax.xml.transform.sax,\
 javax.xml.transform.stax,\
 javax.xml.transform.stream,\
 javax.xml.validation,\
 javax.xml.ws,\
 javax.xml.ws.handler,\
 javax.xml.ws.handler.soap,\
 javax.xml.ws.http,\
 javax.xml.ws.soap,\
 javax.xml.ws.spi,\
 javax.xml.ws.spi.http,\
 javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing,\
 javax.xml.xpath,\
 org.ietf.jgss,\
 org.omg.CORBA,\
 org.omg.CORBA_2_3,\
 org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable,\
 org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage,\
 org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage,\
 org.omg.CORBA.portable,\
 org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage,\
 org.omg.CosNaming,\
 org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage,\
 org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage,\
 org.omg.Dynamic,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage,\
 org.omg.IOP,\
 org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage,\
 org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage,\
 org.omg.Messaging,\
 org.omg.PortableInterceptor,\
 org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.portable,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage,\
 org.omg.SendingContext,\
 org.omg.stub.java.rmi,\
 org.w3c.dom,\
 org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,\
 org.w3c.dom.css,\
 org.w3c.dom.events,\
 org.w3c.dom.html,\
 org.w3c.dom.ls,\
 org.w3c.dom.ranges,\
 org.w3c.dom.stylesheets,\
 org.w3c.dom.traversal,\
 org.w3c.dom.views,\
 org.w3c.dom.xpath,\
 org.xml.sax,\
 org.xml.sax.ext,\
 org.xml.sax.helpers
```

Rudolf Hornig

Answer (score 0):

By doing an "apt-get upgrade" (Ubuntu 18-04), the Java version on my system changed from 10 to 11 and the same issue arose for me.

I was able to successfully re-add Java 10 to make Omnet work by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507161/4712751) (Follow the **Option 2: Manual Installation**, because the referenced PPA in **Option 1** does not contain Java 10 anymore !). I downloaded the JDK-10 from [here](http://jdk.java.net/archive/) for this manual installation.