# Change Java version in a terminal session (Mac OSX)

Tags: java, session, command-line, terminal, version

How do I change the Java version in a terminal session? I don't want to change my system preferences, or my default JRE/JDK. Only for the current terminal session. My OS is Mac OSX, but for completion you might as well specify Windows and Linux.

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: which OS you have? this is a solution for Windows: https://blogs.oracle.com/pranav/switch-between-different-jdk-versions-in-windows this is for Mac: https://gist.github.com/ntamvl/5f4dbaa8f68e6897b99682a395a44c2e

Comment: And this is for linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507160/how-to-install-jdk-10-under-ubuntu/53083341#53083341

Comment: My OS is Mac OSX

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Not a duplicate! The linked question asks for a way to change the DEFAULT compiler. I want to change it for just the current session.

Comment: It is the same, just don't put it in your .bash_profile.

Comment: Fine, but no answer on the linked question mentions that. It's a different question, and should be answered independently