# Change JAVA_HOME value in Linux Mint 19x

Tags: java

I have a linux mint 19x and if I do:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME >> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I want to change the path to put Java 11, but not in the .bashrc, .profile, /etc/enviroment file, I see my JAVA_HOME defined

I tried to put the JAVA_HOME path in my /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Can someone tell me where my JAVA_HOME can be defined, so I can change it well.

Comment: tried export JAVA_HOME=YOURPATH ?

Comment: _Off-Topic_: This may be of your interest (since it handles this change of what java you're using in a given time from shell): [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) and [How to install JDK under Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083341/5640649)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the command line, you can simply change your `JAVA_HOME` variable path:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Then redefine the current path prefixing the jdk binaries:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

*NB: This will only take effect within the current terminal session.*

Answer (score 0):

Another great option is to use `SDKMan` to manage `SDK`s like Java and so on.

I use all the time on all my Linux machines and it's very easy to switch between Java version.

You can find the link here:

https://sdkman.io

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `to use`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check what JDKs you have installed :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
   # And select the usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java version.
   # Also, set the JAVA_HOME variable for Maven to pick the correct JDK:
```

Then :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```